# Duplicate question - I didn't ask the original

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Ok so I want to ask a question "how do you do a str_replace on an OFT file". I have had some fines recently which means I'm loathed to post a question which gets marked as a duplicate. I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810926 may be considered a duplicate but clearly there was no answer and the answer given wasn't sufficient. So how can I ask this question without being considered a duplicate? I've seen duplicate meta questions about asking duplicates - but I didn't ask the original and can't modify/edit it so therefore its not under my control.

Comment: Why don't you add a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to attract more attention (and hopefully better answers) to the existing question?

Comment: Well, this is ironic..

Answer (score 1):

Questions are only considered duplicates if the previous question has an answer to YOUR question. If your question is only partially answered or not at all, then it's not a duplicate of the other question. So if a question has no (real) answers you cannot be a duplicate of it.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

To avoid confusion and being marked as a duplicate you can link to other questions that look similar and point out that they don't answer your question, but you only need to do that if they have answers. It's best to do that at the end of a question to not distract from your real question and explain very briefly why the link didn't help.

That will also show off that you did research and increases the chance of cooperative behaviour/answers from other member of the community.